# Titan: Does Elastic Search store mixed indexes externally?

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

I am new to apache Titan, i got to know we can index titan with Elastic Search. As of i know Elastic search will hold that data that it is indexed.
So my question here is:

If I index titan data with the Elastic Search does it again keeps data or uses the same data ?

I just want to know whether the data will be copied again for indexing.

Answer (score 1):

in titan you can choose to create 2 different indexes:

Simple titan index

Index using external system such as Solr or ElasticSearch

In the second case Elastic Search will create external index files, differents from the Titan ones.

You can take a look to [my gist](https://gist.github.com/MFrancesco/c2e9c38b91f873246251) and create a in-memory graph with Elastic Search, create an Elastic Search index on a property, for example, and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, Elastic Search will create external files in your server for indexes.

If you dislike this, you could use Titan's composite index. Composite indexes use the indexing mechanism of the backend storage you're using (e.g., berkeleyj, cassandra, etc). This means that all indexing will be inside the backend.

For more information, have a look [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html).